# How to render page inside an other page?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there an option in blazor to load a page inside an other page. A version of Html.RenderPartial("page");

This is what I have in asp.net core

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-setting-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-setting" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-setting" aria-selected="true">Setting</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-intent-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-intent" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-intent" aria-selected="false">Intents</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-train-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-train" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-train" aria-selected="false">Train</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-setting" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-setting-tab">
                @{
                    Html.RenderPartial("Setting");
                }
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-intent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-intent-tab">
                @{
                    Html.RenderPartial("Intents");
                }
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-train" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-train-tab">
                @{
                    Html.RenderPartial("../Conversation/Index");
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am just unsure on how I could reproduce something like this in blazor. I look at layout, but I dont want to override the full layout, i just want to seperate my entity between pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what Components are for.  I'd recommend finding a tutorial series on YouTube, or https://blazor-university.com/ if you prefer text, as Components will be one of the first things taught.  If you already have experience, it's probably going to be harder to learn to let go of it than to learn Blazor (which for the most part is pretty simple I think).  That was my experience, anyway. :D